# Vanilla JS xmlhttp request errors 500, but results still appear on form submit?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, xmlhttprequest

I've got a little bit of a conundrum here.

I've got a simple FAQs section running in WordPress, and for styling reasons I need to filter the array through PHP. The problem I'm currently having is that the XML request I'm making through JS is coming out with an error 500, but after the form submits, the data filters.
I want to avoid the submit refresh, and get the data like ajax. Ajax hasn't worked in the ways that I've tried it, so looking for some implementation.

### The PHP display

This script is just for displaying the form, and also displaying the results. But I want to get these results asynchronously to display them.

```php
<?php

function faqs_display() {

    include( dirname(__FILE__, 2) . '/faq-results.php');
    
    ?>
    <div class="faqs-search">
        <form method="post" name="faqs-search-form" id="faqs-search-form">
            <select name="category" id="category">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select a category...</option>
                <option value="none">None</option>
                <option value="web-dev">Web Dev</option>
                <option value="ecommerce">Ecommerce</option>
                <option value="paid-ads">Paid Ads</option>
                <option value="branding">Branding</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="faqs-container">
        <div class="faqs-half">
            <?php foreach($faqs as $key => $faq) { 
                if($key % 2 == 0) { ?>
                <div class="single-faq <?php foreach($faq['categories'] as $key => $cat) { echo $cat . ' '; } ?>">
                    <h4><?php echo $faq['question']; ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $faq['answer']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php }
            } ?>
        </div>
        <div class="faqs-half">
            <?php foreach($faqs as $key => $faq) { 
                if($key % 2 != 0) { ?>
                <div class="single-faq <?php foreach($faq['categories'] as $key => $cat) { echo $cat . ' '; } ?>">
                    <h4><?php echo $faq['question']; ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $faq['answer']; ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php }
            } ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php

}

add_shortcode('faqs-display', 'faqs_display');

?>
```

### The JS

This is the script that does the request. When we change the "category" select, I want to run this async function to force a data sort.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    /* ========== Global Functions JS ========== */
    document.getElementById("category").addEventListener("change", filterFAQs)
    setTimeout(function(){ 

    }, 1000);
    /* ========== Global Functions JS END ========== */
});

async function filterFAQs() {
    // e.preventDefault;
    var category = document.getElementById('category').value;
    var faqs = document.getElementsByClassName('single-faq');
    var form = document.getElementById('faqs-search-form');
    
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open("POST", "faq-results.php", true);
    var params = "category=" + category;
    http.send(params);
    http.onload = function () {
        alert(http.status.toString() + ': ' + http.statusText);
    }

    form.submit()
    return false;
}
```

### The PHP script to parse

This is the PHP that the JS calls on, as well as the one that's included in the display PHP.

```php
<?php

    $faqs = [];
    $i = 0;

    $query = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'faq',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    ));

    while($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $question = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'question', true );
        $answer = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'answers', true );
        $categories = [];

        if(
            str_contains(strtolower($question), 'web dev') || str_contains(strtolower($answer), 'web dev')
        ) {
            array_push($categories, 'web-dev');
        }
        if(
            str_contains(strtolower($question), 'branding') || str_contains(strtolower($answer), 'branding') ||
            str_contains(strtolower($question), 'logo') || str_contains(strtolower($answer), 'logo')
        ) {
            array_push($categories, 'branding');
        }
        if(
            str_contains(strtolower($question), 'paid ad') || str_contains(strtolower($answer), 'paid ad') ||
            str_contains(strtolower($question), 'keywords') || str_contains(strtolower($answer), 'keywords')
        ) {
            array_push($categories, 'paid-ads');
        }
        if(
            str_contains(strtolower($question), 'ecommerce') || str_contains(strtolower($answer), 'ecommerce') ||
            str_contains(strtolower($question), 'e-commerce') || str_contains(strtolower($answer), 'e-commerce')
        ) {
            array_push($categories, 'ecommerce');
        }

        $faqs[$i]['question'] = $question;
        $faqs[$i]['answer'] = $answer;
        $faqs[$i]['categories'] = $categories;

        $i++;

        if(isset($_POST['category'])) {
            $faqs_filtered = [];
            $j = 0;
            foreach($faqs as $key => $faq) {
                if(in_array($_POST['category'], $faq['categories'])) {
                    $faqs_filtered[$j]['question'] = $faq['question'];
                    $faqs_filtered[$j]['answer'] = $faq['answer'];
                    $faqs_filtered[$j]['categories'] = $faq['categories'];
                }
                $j++;
            }
            $faqs = $faqs_filtered;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($faqs);
?>
```

What happens is that when I send the alert, I get "500: " which means I've got an error 500. But when the alert is closed and the page is refreshed by the submit (which I don't want it to refresh, but we'll worry about that later), the results JSON appears as it should. I just want to skip the refreshing part, and have the results display when the select is changed.

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: So why are you submitting a form?

Comment: @JanPfeifer just so that I can check that the data is actually going through. Which given that after said submission the data changes, that means the data is going through. But for some reason, it's not going through properly in the xmlhttpsrequest, as the alert 500 indicates.

Comment: This does not make the sense. By submitting a form you are in fact reloading whole page. The form is submiting to page itself. XMLHttpRequest is asynchronous so onload may even fail to execute when page is reloaded.

Comment: Right. That makes sense @JanPfeifer. However, that doesn't help me in trying to get my response to work. How can I get my PHP to submit asynchronously without constantly erroring? The point I was trying to prove with the submit is that the data DOES come through correctly, but not at the time of the xmlhttprequest. Which is where the confusion comes.

Comment: @JanPfeifer Surely if all was fine, then the xmlhttprequest would submit and I wouldn't get an error 500. But the point I'm making is that it does get an error 500, but I don't know if it's to do with the js or the PHP, as when the form submits and the page refreshes, the PHP seems to function correctly. Which means the PHP won't function on that xmlhttpsrequest, but it will function after the form submission? This is the main dilemma.

Comment: so we are dealing only with that invalid 500 error. I am not sure now but try:  `http.open("POST", "faq-results.php?category="+category, true);` instead of sending category in `params`. In any case 500 is internal server error which will be logged in server logs.

Comment: Agreed, you need to check the server error logs (could be PHP or possibly Apache) to see what specifically is causing the fault.

Comment: Just a question @JanPfeifer, if my form is a post, why would I open a url with my query in it? Doesn't that make it a get request rather than a post request? Other than that I'll need to take a look at getting the logs and get back to you.

Comment: @Tony Ingall Well using GET method would be more appropriate. In a lot of cases it does not realy matter. Adding "?category=id" query string does not turn GET request to POST. I am not sure how String as a payload parameter is treated. I assume that is plain text POST body which you should have to parse manually and so it would be different than form POST request. Instead of String payload in send method you should use FormData object.